# iOS - using MapKit with plist annotations - how do I search within a position radius

Tags: annotations, plist, mapkit

I have an application that uses the Mapkit with a plist that contains my custom annotations. This all works fine.

What I next want to do outside of the map is to be able to locate all the custom annotations that are with say a 10 mile radius of my location or a location I select.

I simply want to return the list of annotations that meet that criteria and present them in a list view.

Any ideas what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer for you, but I think you want to look at using `CLRegion` in Core Location and then passing the coordinates for your annotations into `containsCoordinate:` on that region to see if the annotation lies within the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create CLLocation objects out of your data, which you must be capable of doing if you;re able to get them to your map, you can then compare their distances to the location of your choice using [distanceFromLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a)